# version java for angular and soap websevices

Tags: java, angular, soap, version

I have a question, we have an existing project with java 6 and GWT and we want to migrate to angular (we are using soap web services)
Is java 6 works with angular ? (backend)
If not, must I use java 8 ?
Angular works with soap web services or we must go for Rest ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a TypeScript library for front end that on it's own wouldn't need Java. Perhaps you mistook it for Javascript? These are two different things. When it comes to Java version usage, I would discourage using Java 6, it's old and many improvements have been released since, I would say start with at the least 8, but 9 would be good considering it's modules. Currently Java 16 is being released

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes I mean which version of java i need to use in backend, so I can have a full stack application, exemple using java 6 in backend and angular 9 in front, that will work ? or I need to have java8 in backend

Comment: Both Java versions will work, but as mentioned before I would discourage Java 6 purely from the perspective of how old it is, so my advise would be to go with at least 8.

Comment: Yes I understand, because we have an existing project with java 6 and GWT and we want to migrate, that's why I asked this question, so we can migrate gwt to angular and let java 6, but I was wondering if java 6 is working and compatible with angular and we will not have any errors or problems

Comment: Angular doesn't need to know about what back-end language you're using, not to mention the version. Angular it's a front-end framework and it only needs to be compatible with any other front-end libraries that you might use and because Angular requires Node.js you need to make sure you use the right version for the latter.

Comment: thanks for your responses, I understand now and i can use any version of java. my second question can angular interact with soap webservices  ?